# Unable to keep commands with special characters in sed

Tags: shell, sed, datastage

I want to find and replace all trademark symbols enclosed in double quotesin a file by double quotes

When I fire this command in Linux box its working fine.

```
sed -i 's/\"®"/\""/g' filename
```

But when I copy this command in a script using vi, it's getting pasted as

```
sed -i 's/\"Â®"/\""/g'
```

How to fix it.

I have kept this command directly in datastage job after sub routine but it is not working.

Comment: In short, shell scripts handle the ASCII character set. There are some extended ASCII shell will support -- but that is based on the individual terminal, and character-set supported. You script content is not ASCII, and looks more like Unicode - for which there is no support. You say copyright -- but which one? What character set is it coming from? Is it a UTF-16 code point? The commands line `printf` do have output support for UTF-8 (mostly), but that doesn't apply outside of the `printf` command.

Comment: You'll probably want all involved software to handle (or at least pass through) UTF-8 (or the encoding you used, if not UTF-8). You'll also want to set `locale`, which many tools use to see which encoding to use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ensure your script is in ASCII